# Error in MDX Query for ASO calc scripts

Tags: mdx

I have a calculation script for an ASO cube which copies data from one version to another . in my POV section of the code i am using crossjoin function of MDX to create a set of tuples

```
POV "Crossjoin({Filter([Accounts].Members, IsLeaf([Accounts].CurrentMember))},

Crossjoin ({[D100]},

Crossjoin ({[2014]},{[USD]})))"

SourceRegion "Crossjoin({[ACTL]}, {[EOP]})" ;
```

but on execution this MDX using Maxl i am getting the following error

```
MaxL Shell completed with error

ERROR - 1300033 - Upper-level members, for example [AC0001], are not allowed in argument [POV]. Select a level-0 member.

ERROR - 1241190 - Custom Calculation terminated with Essbase error 1300033 in POV.
```

I am using Filter function to filter out all the lev 0 members from my account dimension in POV section, somehow still its returning parent level members. I also tried `[Accounts].Levels(0).Members`

but faced the same problem.

Can anyone help me out with where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Calculation scripts are typically used to calculate the Accounts that are derived from the Input Accounts in one Application.Database.  A calculation script uses consolidation operators (+) or formulas usually in BSO.

Assuming you are trying to extract a portion of data from one ASO Application.Database to another Application.Database, one option is to use a report script with syntax similar to the following to extract Level 0 members only.  You can right click on the report script in Essbase Administration Services and execute it.  Report scripts are usually much easier to write than Multi-Dimensional Expressions.  Above you state that you are trying to filter out Level 0 members when ASOs always need to be loaded at Level 0.  They will roll up to the higher levels in the Outline.

To load the text file extract, build a rules file and validate it in EAS (you can also use EAS to load directly from relational database tables).  Select "File" - "Open Data File".  Once the file is validated you can use EAS to load the file into the other Application.Database.  Once you complete the process in EAS you can automate it using MAXL code and run the process from the command prompt.

If you are trying to copy or mirror an entire Application.Database, right click on the Application and select copy in Essbase Administration Services.